# How can I realistically fund a political movement against Summer Time in western Europe?

Tags: europe, civil-rights, protests

As the time of writing this, we are a few days after switching to Daylight Saving Time, a.k.a Summer Time, that is setting clocks one hour too early.

This particular clock regime is effective in western/central Europe (CET) timezone every year between end of March until end of October, that is 7 months in total, or roughly 60% of the time. Hence the *special* clock regime is in effect more often than not.

I am strongly oposed to changing the time twice per year, for many reasons. I know I am not alone being opposed to the principle, as I also hear many other people are annoyed by this practice.

[Switzerland has voted against summer time in may 1978](https://www.admin.ch/ch/f/pore/va/19780528/det283.html), but the vote was not respected, because it was according to them, not realistic to have a different timezone for only our small country, enclaved in another time zone.

Complaining individually will *never* have any effect on politics, hence the question : **How can I use my civil rights efficiently to protest against summer time on a realistic level, not only in Switzerland but also internationally in the whole continent?**

Comment: What do you mean with "on a realistic level"? Are 100k followers on a Facebook group "a realistic level"? And btw: Maybe you don't have to do anything, because the [EU want to change it anyway](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-45366390) .-)

Answer (score 4):

According to http://www.europarl.europa.eu/atyourservice/en/20150201PVL00037/Petitions

> One of the fundamental rights of European citizens: Any citizen,
>   acting individually or jointly with others, may at any time exercise
>   his right of petition to the European Parliament under Article 227 of
>   the Treaty on the Functioning of the European Union.
>
> Any citizen of the European Union, or resident in a Member State, may,
>   individually or in association with others, submit a petition to the
>   European Parliament on a subject which comes within the European
>   Union's fields of activity and which affects them directly. Any
>   company, organisation or association with its headquarters in the
>   European Union may also exercise this right of petition, which is
>   guaranteed by the Treaty.
>
> A petition may take the form of a complaint or a request and may
>   relate to issues of public or private interest.
>
> The petition may present an individual request, a complaint or
>   observation concerning the application of EU law or an appeal to the
>   European Parliament to adopt a position on a specific matter. Such
>   petitions give the European Parliament the opportunity of calling
>   attention to any infringement of a European citizen's rights by a
>   Member State or local authorities or other institution.

You probably don't need funding unless you're planning on hosting/attending events, so social media could be a good platform. If you do need funding, crowdfunding is a possibility if you can make a convincing case.

Comment: So basically I'd have to fund an organisation or association in a member state, i.e. outside Switzerland (for example in France)?

Comment: @bregalad That would appear to be the most efficient approach. I'm hazy on the agreements between Switzerland and the EU, but if you want to change the EU, it'd be simpler if you lived there.